# How to do simple calculation in LaTeX?

Tags: calculations

Consider the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\sxfigure}[4]{
\includegraphics[width=#1*#3 cm, height=#2*#3 cm]{#4}
}
```

`#1` and `#2` is some value to determine the width and height of the figure, `#3` is to control the zoom ratio. However, the above code doesn't work. Could someone provide a solution? I have tried the following, still not work. Could some point out the mistake?

```
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand{\sxmultiply}[2]{\pgfmathparse{#1*#2}\pgfmathresult}
\newcommand{\sxfigure}[5]{
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=$\sxmultiply{#3}{#5}$ cm, height=$\sxmultiply{#4}{#5}$ cm]{#1}
\end{center}
\caption{#2}
\end{figure}
}
```

Comment: [-3^{2}+1 \div 4 \times \frac{1}{4}-\left|-1 \frac{1}{4}\right| \times(-0.5)^{2}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3%5E%7B2%7D%2B1+%5Cdiv+4+%5Ctimes+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7D-%5Cleft%7C-1+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7D%5Cright%7C+%5Ctimes%28-0.5%29%5E%7B2%7D)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`fp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) is an easy-to-use arithmetic bundle that could help here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\newcommand{\sxfigure}[4]{%
  \FPeval\widthdim{#1*#3}% Calculate width dimension
  \FPeval\heightdim{#2*#3}% Calculate height dimension
  \includegraphics[width=\widthdim cm, height=\heightdim cm]{#4}%
}
\begin{document}
\sxfigure{1}{2}{1.5}{example-image-a} \quad
\sxfigure{1}{2}{1.7}{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

However, I would opt for an improved syntax using a key-value approach for exactly the reason mentioned in the first paragraph of the [`xkeyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xkeyval/doc/xkeyval.pdf):

> Using keys in macro deﬁnition has the advantage that the 9 arguments
>   maximum can easily be avoided and that it reduces confusion in the
>   syntax of your macro when compared to using a lot of (optional)
>   arguments. Compare for instance the following possible syntaxes of the
>   macro `\mybox` which might for instance use its arguments to draw some
>   box containing text
>
> ```
> \mybox[5pt][20pt]{some text}[red][white][blue]
> \mybox[text=red,background=white,frame=blue,left=5pt,right=20pt]{some text}
> ```
>
> Notice that, to be able to specify the frame color in the ﬁrst
>   example, the other colors need to be speciﬁed as well. This is not
>   necessary in the second example and these colors can get preset
>   values. The same thing holds for the margins.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wonder how can someone answer my question so quickly and so detailed.

Answer (score 19):

How about this, using the [`calc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/calc) package

```
\newcommand{\sxfigure}[5]{%
    %   #1: width
    %   #2: height
    %   #3: zoom ratio
    %   #4: image
    %   #5: caption
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width={#1*#3}, height={#2*#3}]{#4}
\caption{#5}
\end{figure}
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Note that I've used the [`mwe`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mwe) just for the images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\sxfigure}[5]{%
    %   #1: width
    %   #2: height
    %   #3: zoom ratio
    %   #4: image
    %   #5: caption
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width={#1*#3}, height={#2*#3}]{#4}
\caption{#5}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\sxfigure{1cm}{1cm}{2}{example-image-a}{my caption}

\sxfigure{1cm}{1cm}{4}{example-image-b}{my other caption}

\end{document}
```

Presumably you might want to `\label` these images too, so perhaps the following would be better

```
\newcommand{\sxfigure}[6]{%
    %   #1: width
    %   #2: height
    %   #3: zoom ratio
    %   #4: image
    %   #5: caption
    %   #6: label
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width={#1*#3}, height={#2*#3}]{#4}
\caption{#5}
\label{#6}
\end{figure}
}
```

Note that I have used `\centering` as detailed in [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)

Answer (score 14):

In your case, as you use `#3` (and `#5` in the second example) only to scale (the factor gets multiplied in both the `width` and the `height` key), you could just use:

```
\newcommand{\sxfigure}[4]{
    \includegraphics[width=#1, height=#2, scale=#3]{#4}
}
```

and use it like

```
\sxfigure{<width length>}{<height length>}{<scale factor>}{<file>}
```

---

The `calc` package can do simple multiplication, though using `pgf` enables all sorts of calculations, for example:

```
\sxfigure[angle=30]{
    image width = 1.1^3*3cm,
    image height = exp(3)*3cm
}{example-image}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newlength{\includewidth}
\newlength{\includeheight}
\pgfset{
    image width/.code={
        \pgfmathsetlength\includewidth{#1}
    },
    image height/.code={
        \pgfmathsetlength\includeheight{#1}
    },
}
\newcommand{\sxfigure}[3][]{% #1 = \includegraphics key-value stuff
                            % #2 = width and height assignments
                            % #3 = the file
    \pgfset{#2}%
    \includegraphics[width=\includewidth, height=\includeheight,#1]{#3}%
}%

\newcommand{\sxFigure}[4][]{% #1 = \includegraphics key-value stuff
                            % #2 = width
                            % #3 = height
                            % #4 = the file
    \pgfmathsetlength\includewidth{#2}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\includeheight{#3}%
    \includegraphics[width=\includewidth, height=\includeheight,#1]{#4}%
}%
\begin{document}
    \sxfigure[angle=30]{image width = 2.5*3cm, image height = 3*3cm}{example-image}

    \sxFigure[angle=30]{2.5*3cm}{3*3cm}{example-image}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

e-TeX's `\dimexpr` can be used:

```
\newcommand{\sxfigure}[4]{%
  \includegraphics[width=#3\dimexpr#1cm\relax, height=#3\dimexpr#2cm\relax]{#4}%
}
```

Comment: Oh no, anything but `\dimexpr`!