# How can I calculate within style values?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, tikz-styles

Is it possible to calculate (addition etc.) in style values? I wanted to do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,chains}

\newcommand*{\mypath}[3][0.0]{% looseness adjustment (optional),1st node, 2nd node
    \draw (#2.south east) to [in=90, out=90, looseness=0.85+#1] (#3.south west);
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
    \node[on chain] (k11) {};
    \node[on chain] (k12) {};
    \mypath{k11}{k12}       
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

The problem is `looseness=0.85+#1` which fails with `Missing number, treated as zero` and `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)`.

Comment: A better approach would be writing your own `/.style`s instead of nesting macros to avoid such problems.

Comment: @percusse I don't like it either, but I don't know yet how I should transform my path operations into a style, I'll have to read the manual a bit more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to parse the number into a macro and use the macro as the argument to the key.

But, the reason this has to be done is that the `looseness` keys do not appear to be parsed using `pgfmath`. So, for fans of hacking:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,chains}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@to@set@in@looseness#1{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}\let\tikz@to@in@looseness=\pgfmathresult%
  \let\tikz@to@end@compute=\tikz@to@end@compute@looseness%
  \tikz@to@switch@on%
}
\def\tikz@to@set@out@looseness#1{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}\let\tikz@to@out@looseness=\pgfmathresult%
  \let\tikz@to@start@compute=\tikz@to@start@compute@looseness%
  \tikz@to@switch@on%
}


\newcommand*{\mypath}[3][0.0]{% looseness adjustment (optional),1st node, 2nd node
    \draw (#2.south east) to [in=90, out=90, looseness=0.85+#1] (#3.south west);
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
    \node[on chain] (k11) {};
    \node[on chain] (k12) {};
    \mypath[-0.5]{k11}{k12}       
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm! How nice, what about the other keys? Is there a list which ones are parsed by `pgfmath`?

Comment: @neo All keys that requires real or integer values should be parsed as mathematical expression. It is not the case of `looseness`. I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another way is to fill a macro with the expression. (So there is no need to make the option math parseable)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,chains}


\newcommand{\mypath}[3][0.0]{% looseness adjustment (optional),1st node, 2nd node
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mytemp}{.85+ #1}
    \draw (#2.south east) to [looseness=\mytemp,in=90, out=90, ] (#3.south west);
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
    \node[on chain] (k11) {};
    \node[on chain] (k12) {};
    \mypath[1]{k11}{k12} 
    \mypath[0]{k11}{k12} 
\end{tikzpicture}    


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach to the same fundemental issue (the need to do floating-point maths on the value), this time using LaTeX3's FPU

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,chains}

\newcommand*{\mypath}[3][0.0]{% looseness adjustment (optional),1st node, 2nd node
    \draw (#2.south east) to [in=90, out=90, looseness=\fpeval{0.85+#1}] (#3.south west);
}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
    \node[on chain] (k11) {};
    \node[on chain] (k12) {};
    \mypath{k11}{k12}       
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

(The LaTeX3 code is expandable, so can simply be dropped in to a place where the underlying TikZ code needs some form of number.)

Answer (score 3):

Using the `fp` package works, as explained in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87824/how-to-do-simple-calculation-in-latex).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,chains}

\newcommand*{\mypath}[3][0.0]{% looseness adjustment (optional),1st node, 2nd node
    \FPeval\loose{0.85+(#1)}
    \draw   (#2.south east) to [in=90, out=90, looseness=\loose] (#3.south west);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]

    \node[on chain] (k11) {};
    \node[on chain] (k12) {};

    \mypath[4.0]{k11}{k12}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```